Commas disappearing from SharePoint list item record when submitting form from PowerApps
One of the user in our environment is facing strange issue that when he is submitting the form with commas in one text field like "1,20,000", commas are getting disappeared from record when save in SharePoint list in a single line of text field and data is stored like "120000".
Similar issue i remembered i fixed by changing the default language of user's browser of an Italian user i think but this time the user has same language settings of browser like other users. Any idea why commas are disappearing for the user?
For all other users and me, it is working fine. User checked in some other machine too, but same issue persists.

User has a locale that contains commas as separators-of-three, but SharePoint regional-settings do not have them. So user can input them as much as like, but eventually they will be parsed and saved according to site settings.
